# Use C++ with Android ndk/jni

Tags: c++, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

All the ndk samples only make use of basic C functions declared as extern in the header and defined in the cpp file. Then after including the header file in the C file containing the jni callback, everything works fine.

Is it possible to use C++ classes with the android ndk? My application is not going to be a native activity, it will still have an important java part but it will call native C code for CPU-intensive computation (already written in C++, with classes and other C++ stuff).

Here is my hello-world like strcuture for now:

File "first.h"

```
#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H

class Test
{};

#endif /* FIRST_H */
```

File "second.cpp"

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "first.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

jint Java_com_example_twolibs_TwoLibs_add( JNIEnv*  env,
                                      jobject  this,
                                      jint     x,
                                      jint     y )
{
    Test t;
    return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And finally Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libtwolib-second
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := second.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Pretty basic but that does not compile. Turning second.cpp in a .c file raises an error when including the header file, I guess this is because it is not a C++ file.

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Test'
```

Making it .cpp raises the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r5c/samples/twolibs/jni/second.c', needed by `/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r5c/samples/two-libs/obj/local/armeabi/objs/twolib-second/second.o'.  Stop.
```

Any idea how I can make that thing compile?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use C++ with NDK, but files with C++ code must have .cpp extension.

From **ANDROID-MK.html**:

> Note that the default extension for C++ source files is '.cpp'. It is
>   however possible to specify a different one by defining the variable
>   LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION. Don't forget the initial dot (i.e. '.cxx' will
>   work, but not 'cxx').

Comment: It seems like the callback C code (the file containing calls like Java_com_example_twolibs_TwoLibs_add to be called from the java side ) has to be in a .c file (not .cpp). Otherwise it does not compile on my machine. Therefore when I try to include a header file containing a class declaration, the same error comes up.

Comment: Turing everything into .cpp files gives me a  make: *** No rule to make target error which means the make file could not find the source files... but it does if I turn them into .c files so this is not a path problem I guess

Comment: It must compile, but you need to add `external "C"` to all JNI functions. Have you changed source file extension in the makefile?

Comment: Yes I tried to add extern "C" around jni functions (I also updated my code in the post) but still the same error  "make: *** No rule to make target...". The file extension is also correct in the make file

Comment: Ok got it, your solution was actually correct, but I forgot to clean some .o files therefore make was still looking for the .c file. Once I cleaned everything and ran a fresh ndk-build, everything worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will have to recompile all the native libraries specifically for Android. You do need the source code for all 3rd party native libs you plan to use simply because Usually when we compile and link these libraries outside Android they are linked to `glibc` but unfortunately Android doesn't use `glibc` due to liscence and performance issues. Android uses a watered down version of `glibc` called `libc`. It has matching symbol names to glibc for most of the usual functionalities. But as far as i know the libc doesn't have some functionality related to `strings` and it definitely doesnt have some `posix` support. If your native libraries are using any of the deprecated functionality you will have to find workaround for those by using alternative functionality supported by `libc` and coding your libs accordingly.

Also, as you righty pointed out you will have to use the NDK to interface Java(Android app/fwk) to native world(C++).

Though this sounds pretty simple in my experience compiling native libraries on Android(Android porting) has traditionally been very time consuming with no guarantee of sucesses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I can't even get started on porting my 3rd party libs since I can't even get a simple hello-world-like test to compile as soon as I use classes in it.The first step would be to create a nearly empty native C++ test class and use it in my jni callback C file. Just to see if that compiles.

Answer (score 1):

About your compiling error, seems like you first called it "second.c" and later renamed it to "second.cpp" but the object files still have the "second.c" name in them so before you compile (bdk-build) you need to remove the *.o and *.d files in /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r5c/samples/two-libs/obj/local/armeabi/objs/twolib-second/ directory

Answer (score 0):

> error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__ attribute __' before 'class'

Classic case of missing ';' before the class keyword? Imagine

```
 int functionname(int p)
 class X { } ;
```

This could lead to your compiler message quite easily. A common complicating factor is when it actually looks like

```
 #include "someheader.h"
 class X { } ;
```

and the error is in the last declaration inside someheader.h /or any recursively included file/ ;)

Comment: That's what I thought at first but I checked and this is not a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
ndk-build clean
```

after you modify a wrong `Android.mk`, or else the build may continue to fail even if you've fixed the configuration.

I think this is what the OP meant [on this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423078/use-c-with-android-ndk-jni#comment7552680_6423293).

Answer (score 0):

Edit Android.mk

Modify the instances of LOCAL_SRC_FILES and remove the ./ from the begginning of each line.