# Optimising native Android code - compiler flags

Tags: java, android, eclipse, optimization, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android app which uses native c++ code with ndk.

It is very important that this code runs as fast and efficient as possible. Any tips here? Is there a way to set the -o3 flag for instance in the Android.mk file?

Thanks!

Comment: Browse this links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423078/use-c-with-android-ndk-jni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep, just add LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O2 for C/C++ code

or LOCAL_CPPFLAGS for C++ code. these go in our Android.mk file.